# Express: serving static files not working

Tags: node.js, express

This is my project structure:

```
-backend
 -server.js
-www
 -index.html
 -app.css
 -bundle.js
```

I am getting problem with Express not being able to serve static files with urls having 2+ slashes like this

```
localhost:3000/product/1
```

but it works fine for URLs with only 1 slash :

```
localhost:3000/register
localhost:3000/home
```

Problem occurs as it always tries to get

> localhost:3000/product/1/app.css

and

> localhost:3000/product/1/bundle.js

when go to

> localhost:3000/product/1

This is my configuration in server.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../www')));
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../www', 'index.html'))
});
```

Comment: Make sure, in the HTML, you're linking to "/app.css" instead of just "app.css". The latter will look for app.css at the current URL instead of from the root. This doesn't sound like an issue with your static assets.

Comment: Agree with @danneu. If you refer to the static files with root context using /filename.ext then everything should work fine.

Comment: I'm actually using "./app.css" and "./bundle.js" in my index file. I think that shouldnt cause the problem.

Comment: Tried again. It turns out that "/bundle.js" works. Thanks @danneu and flexdinesh :)

Comment: @sharius2301 fwiw, "./app.css" and "app.css" both mean "look for app.css at the current path", path being whatever is in the url bar. "/app.css" means an absolute lookup from the root, i.e. ignoring the current path in the url bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using "./bundle.js" and "./app.css" in index.html. Changed to "/bundle.js" and "/app.cs" and got it working. Thanks to comments under post !